Is there any simple version control system that is secure by default?
For text file version control on external drives which are plugged into different computers I need a version control system that is not less secure than usual file system access (e.g., from a Linux operating system).
Popular version control systems such as Git or Mercurial offer the execution of hooks that can contain arbitrary code. Unfortunately, if hook executables exist in a version controlled directory, they are executed by default. Through configuration, that could possibly be prevented. But opt-out is always worse than opt-in, when it comes to security. (That is why newly created files on a Linux system are not executable by default.)
Is there any alternative to Git/Mercurial/Fossil/... that can be used for local version control (unlike Subversion which always requires a server) without having to fear arbitrary code execution?

Would you mind sharing more context for your need? Is it for collaborating with other people?

Yes exactly. Simple serverless collaboration involving more than one computer, which is the security threat external drives are oftentimes exposed to. Usually, in suchlike scenarios, it is not recommended for a computer system to silently run executables on the drive (but this is what version control systems usually do when running hooks).

I have to add that version control is not required by the collaboration process itself. It is simply for individual authors of individual text files to be able to step back to older revisions of the files, and (optionally) sometimes individual authors of individual directories and their text file contents to be able to step back to older revisions of the directories and their contents.

SourceSafe. It does not have hooks :-D  And yeah, I think this product is just perfect, since there was no release for more than 19 years. All the bugs have been eliminated and no new features are needed.

@ThomasWeller The problem is: For some reason I seldom trust software that starts with "Microsoft...". Not that it has unfixed bugs that are not "features", but I fear the quick & dirty feeling ;-)

Likewise, RCS or SCCS might be worth looking into. I use RCS myself for personal VC

@jrw32982 Sorry for not being able to upvote your comment because most of my points are in the bounty. For SCCS there are no packages available, but RCS is appealing. However, still I am googling and chatgpting around, not finding an explicit proof of it not providing foreign code execution (hooks,...). And I fear the requirement will come to be able to check in several files in one revision, which RCS does not seem to support.
